# Moving many files into multiple subfolders using Python or tool

Tags: python, directory

Im completely new at python and have been given a task at work, im entirely in over my head with this one however.

I have thousands of images with the naming convention AAAAA_BBBBB_CCCCC.png
they all need to go from the root folder into subfolders so it looks like this.

Root---->AAAAA------>BBBBB

so all images need to be in their BBBBB folder but AAAAA is their model name, and BBBBB is their serial number

So they need to be sorted into potentially hundreds of subfolders based on their AAAAA and BBBBB values.

Id appreciate some elucidation on the matter.

Ive tried shutil but im stumped as to how to sort by their AAAAA and BBBBB values.

Comment: Welcome to SO @pigge. Please can you share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, well im not competent enough yet to do anything on my own, but through some googling i found this, however im not proficient enough to use it, and I think its missing the sorting component i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will achieve what you want. It will go over all the files and use system calls to create folders, subfolders and copy the files into them. Please go over a basic python course and try to understand the code. It will help you alot.

```py
import os, glob
from shutil import copyfile

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/"

print(path)

for file in glob.glob("*_*_*.png"):
    values = file[:-4].split("_")
    print(values)
    directory = path + values[0] + "/" + values[1]
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    copyfile(path + file, directory + "/" + file)
```